# is there a way to use angular material auto-complete for multi fields? I got a task and can't solve this issue without repeating the same function

Tags: angular, angular-material

is there a way to use angular material autocomplete for multi fields, 10 fields at least? I got a task and can't solve it Because of this issue, can I create a generic function for each mat-autocomplete without repeating the same function?

```html
 <mat-form-field class="col-4" appearance="fill">
              <mat-label>{{ "SIZE_UNITS" | translate }}</mat-label>
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="SIZE_UNITS"
                id="select_size_type"
                matInput
                formControlName="sizeTypeId"
                [matAutocomplete]="auto"
              />
              <mat-autocomplete
                #auto="matAutocomplete"
                (optionSelected)="changeSizeType($event)"
              >
                <mat-option
                  id="{{ st.id }}sizeUnits"
                  [value]="st.name"
                  *ngFor="let st of filteredValues"
                  >{{ st.name }}</mat-option
                >
              </mat-autocomplete>
            </mat-form-field>
```

```html
   <mat-form-field class="col-3" appearance="fill">
              <input
                type="text"

                placeholder="teeesting "
                matInput
                [formControl]="myControl"
                [matAutocomplete]="autoo"
              />

              <mat-autocomplete #autoo="matAutocomplete">
                <mat-option
                  *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async"
                  [value]="option"
                >
                  {{ option }}
                </mat-option>
              </mat-autocomplete>
            </mat-form-field>
```

ts code

```js
 private _filter(value: string): string[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

    return this.options.filter((option) =>
      option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue)
    );
  }
```

ngoninit

```js
this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map((value) => this._filter(value))
    );

    this.filteredOptions2 = this.myControl2.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map((value) => this._filter(value))
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid repeated code, I recommend to create a custom **AutocompleteComponent**, that can later be called multiple times from the parent-component.

The **Autocomplete-Component TS** could look something like this:

```
export class AutocompleteComponent {
  @Input() options: string[];
  @Input() selectedValue: string;
  @Output() selectedValueChange = new EventEmitter<string>();

  filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;

  constructor(private formControl: FormControl) {
    this.filteredOptions = formControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map((value) => this._filter(value))
    );
  }

  displayFn(option: string): string {
    return !!option ? option : '';
  }

  private _filter(value: string): string[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

    return this.options.filter((option) =>
      option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue)
    );
  }

  onSelectionChange(value: string) {
    this.selectedValueChange.emit(value);
  }
}
```

And then the **Autocomplete-Component-HTML**:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input type="text" matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" (ngModelChange)="onSelectionChange($event)">
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
      {{option}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

The **Parent-Component TS** (Here you can use the same array of options for multiple instances of the AutocompleteComponent):

```
export class AppComponent {
  form = new FormGroup({
    selectedOption1: new FormControl(''),
    selectedOption2: new FormControl('')
  });
  // Can be used for multiple instances of autocomplete:
  autocompleteOptions = ['Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3'];
}
```

The **Parent-Component HTML**:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <app-autocomplete
    formControlName="selectedOption1"
    [options]="autocompleteOptions">
  </app-autocomplete>
  <app-autocomplete
    formControlName="selectedOption2"
    [options]="autocompleteOptions">
  </app-autocomplete>
</form>
```